# Probability of two Brownian motions are $r$-distance near each other

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

What is the probability that the graph of two independent Brownian motions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ starting at origin  on $t \in [0,n]$ are within $R$-distance to each other. In other words, what is $P(dist(B^0[0,n], B^1[0,n]) < R))$?

My idea: the difference of the Brownian motions is also a Brownian motion. So first take the difference and find the probability of hitting time to the ball of radius $\frac{R}{2}$ for $B^0-B^1$ being smaller than $n$. Thus we can find a upper bound for the probability by calculating both $P(|B^0-B^1)[0,n]| < \frac{R}{2}))$ and $P(|B^0[0,n]| < \frac{R}{2}))$ to approxmate by triangular inequality. And then I'm stuck. Any hints will be much appreciated

Comment: If your Brownian motions both start at the origin, $\text{dist}(B^{0}[0,n], B^{1}[0,n])=0$, since both of the Brownian trajectories contain the origin. You probably want your Brownian motions to start at distinct points $x,y\in{\mathbb{R}^{d}}$ and R>|x-y|, otherwise the problem is trivial.

Comment: Also, applying the Beurling estimate (see section 6.1 of http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/harmonic.pdf) you can show that in two dimensions, $\mathbb{P}(0<\text{dist}(B^{0}[0,n], B^{1}[0,n])<R)$ is small. 

In other words, the probability you're looking at is essentially the probability that your two Brownian motions intersect.

Comment: My apology; the distance I mean is the maximum distance between the two trajectories. So it's the probability that given any point $p$ from one trajectory, the other trajectory is contained in the ball of radius $R$ centered at $p$

Comment: The Wiener sausage may be a useful keyword to find related results

Answer (score 2):

$$\textrm{d}(W_{1,t},W_{2,t})^2=\|W_{1,t}-W_{2,t}\|_2^2=\|X_{t}\|_2^2$$
We have $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}_d(0,2t\mathbf{I}_d)$ and it can be modeled as
$$dX_t=\begin{bmatrix}dX_{1,t} \\ dX_{2,t} \\ .. \\ dX_{d,t} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{2} & ... & 0 \\ ... &  ... & ... & ... \\0 & 0 & ... & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}dB_{1,t} \\ dB_{2,t} \\ ... \\ dB_{d,t} \end{bmatrix}$$
where $B_t$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. Now we want the distribution of
$$X_{1,t}^2+...+X_{d,t}^2=2t(Z_{1,t}^2+...+Z_{d,t}^2)$$
where $Z_{j,t} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. We have $Z_{1,t}^2+...+Z_{d,t}^2 \sim\chi^2_d$ therefore
$$X_{1,t}^2+...+X_{d,t}^2 \sim \Gamma(k=d/2,\theta=4t)$$
So
$$P(\textrm{d}(W_{1,t},W_{2,t})<R)=P(\textrm{d}(W_{1,t},W_{2,t})^2<R^2)=F_\Gamma(R^2)$$
where $F_\Gamma$ is the Gamma cdf.

Comment: Hi Snoop, that's an awesome answer. I think I probably didn't phrase my question well. I am interested in the probability that the "paths" of the Brownian motion are near each other. So not $\sup_{t \in [0, n]} |B^1(t) - B^0(t)|$ but the value of $\sup_{t \in [0, n]}\sup_{s \in [0, n]} |B^1(t) - B^0(s)|$

Comment: Thank you @TheOne. I didn't get the core of the issue. That's a great question